# How to setup angular directive to certain year?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Is there built-in way to make angular directive to certain date in current year? For example I want date in format '2018-03-26' to work as {{date| date:"'current-year'-03-26"}} ?

Or this is certainly something to make custom?

Comment: You mean you want to get the current year? Your question is not clear

Comment: I mean that I want date certain date with current year, e.g '03-26-' + current year..I htought that there is a built-in mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not built-in, but it's rather easy. Make your pipe, and use this transform :

```js
transform(date: Date): Date {
  const sameDateButOnCurrentYear = new Date(date.getTime());
  sameDateButOnCurrentYear.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
  return sameDateButOnCurrentYear;
}
```